# Convergence of Fuchsian groups and existence of suitable homeomorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, quasiconformal

Let $(\Gamma_n)_n$ ($\subset PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$) be a sequence of discrete groups, if we say that $(\Gamma_n)_n$ converges to a group $\Gamma$  this means that there exist isomorphisms $\tau_n:\Gamma\rightarrow\Gamma_n$ such that for all $\sigma\in\Gamma,\tau_n(\sigma)$ converge to $\sigma$.

Do someone have an idea or a reference  about the proof of the following Lemma:

**Lemma:**

Let $(\Gamma_n)_n$ be a sequence of Fuchsian groups converging to a group $\Gamma$ and  $\tau_n$  the isomorphisms  given in the definition above then:

There exist homeomorphisms $\phi_n:\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma\longrightarrow\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma_n$  whose lifts $\tilde{\phi}_n$ satisfies for any $\sigma\in\Gamma$

$$\tilde{\phi}_n\circ\sigma=\tau_n(\sigma)\circ\tilde{\phi}_n$$

and such that  $(\tilde{\phi}_n)_n$ converges to the identity map uniformly on  compact sets i.e that $(\tilde{\phi}_n)$ satisfies,
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{H}^2, \tilde{\phi}_n(x)\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}x$$

($\mathbb{H}^2$ is the hyperbolic plane.)

Thanks for any answer

Comment: I think, this was asked earlier at MSE. The answer, as before, that without further assumptions, your lemma is false.

Comment: @MoisheKohan why it is  false? For me the Lemma is true like that

Comment: You can find a sequence of free groups of infinite rank $\Gamma_n$ converging to a free group of infinite rank $\Gamma$ such that  $H^2/Gamma$ is a planar surface, while each $H^2/\Gamma_n$ has infinitely many handles. Hence, homeomorphisms $\phi_n$ do not exist.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you know if there’s a counterexample with finitely generated groups? Surfaces of finite type feel a bit more tame. Although if you use free groups you might be able to get a planar/handle mismatch...

Comment: @SantanaAfton: Lemma holds for finitely generated groups, but I am not sure the result is stated anywhere in the literature.

Comment: In fairness to the OP, the phrase "Fuchsian groups" is used inconsistently in the literature. Often, it includes the hypothesis of finite generation.